# How to track Jwplayer video events with Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

What code do I add to Jwplayer javascript to get events like what video is playing, when it was watched to the end, watched in full display window and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JW player 6.9 supports universal analytics

http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1417179-integration-with-google-analytics

That support page goes over the integration with Universal Analytics, and what information is sent to GA (Events)